# I am getting data from SqlDataReader and it returns all results into 1 row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using SqlDataReader, and I am able to get data, but it returns it all from the database in 1 row. all the rows in the database into 1, how would I adjust my code so each row in the database is not in 1 row:

```
SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    string data = dataReader.GetValue(i).ToString();
                    items.Add(data);
                }
            }
```

`items` is `private List<string> items;`

Here is my whole code:

```
public class AirportClass
    {
        private string connectionString;
        private SqlConnection connection;
        private SqlCommand command;
        private List<string> items;

        public AirportClass()
        {
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        }

        public List<string> getListItems()
        {
            items = new List<string>();
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * From Table");
            command.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    string data = dataReader.GetValue(i).ToString();
                    items.Add(data);
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
            return items;
        }
    }
```

I am looking for away to have data like this:

`[0] => [0] => 'data`, [1] => 'data', [2] => 'data' [1] => [0] => 'data', [1] => 'data', [2] => 'data'` something for json use later.

Comment: What's `items`? Is it a list of some objects?

Comment: updated question....items is private List<string> items;, I realized that just seconds after I posted, lol

Comment: What is your `SELECT` statement?  The database is going to return whatever data it has in whatever structure you request it.  It's not really clear what the problem is.  Nor is it at all clear what you're doing with that data, since you seem to be entirely ignoring the concept of "rows" and just appending each individual value to the same list of strings...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @David I get that I am appending each value to the same list of string, would changing the string into an array help?

Comment: @user3723240: I guess the question is, what format do you *want* this data in?  Normally I would define a class which represents one "record" in the data, with properties corresponding to values in that record.  Then for each row in the results I'd build an instance of that class and add it to a list of that class.  So the result from the method is a list of business objects rather than a list of strings.

Comment: We have no idea whether “changing the string into an array” will help because we don't know [what you're trying to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). `SELECT * From Table` is unlikely to be a useful query. What are you going to be doing with `items`?

Comment: I am eventually going to need this data to converted into json data, I have updated my question with an example on how I would like it to look like,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning a list of strings, which basically means that no sets of values in that list are meaningfully associated with one another.  For example, say you have two records:

```
ID    Name
----------
1     David
2     Michael
```

Then your resulting data would look like this:

```
1
David
2
Michael
```

Which loses all meaning of what a "record" is in the original data.  There's no difference between an `ID` or a `Name` in your `List<string>`.

Instead, create a class to represent your data.  In my example it could be as simple as:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then return a `List<Person>` instead of a `List<string>`, thus retaining the conceptual meaning of individual records in the data.  You'd build that list with something like:

```
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    var person = new Person();

    var id = 0;
    var idValue = dataReader.GetValue(0);
    if (int.TryParse(idValue, out id))
        person.ID = id;
    else
    {
        // ID was invalid, handle the error here
    }

    person.Name = dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString();

    people.Add(person);
}
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch, good answer.

Comment: I have created my Person class and I am calling that class and setting my values, but I am still getting an error on items.Add(person) 'The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Add(string)' has some invalid argumenets' what is people?

Comment: @user3723240: Did you change it to a `List<Person>` instead of a `List<string>`?  In my example `people` is the `List<Person>`.  C# is a statically typed language, you need to define the correct types for your values.

Comment: The function that this code is inside is public List<string> getListItems() and the function calling this is also public List<string> getListItems() (this function is in the controller)

Comment: @user3723240: Right, and you'd need to change that to `List<Person>` (or a list of whatever your class is called).  `string` can't be used to store any kind of type, only strings.

Comment: Now its working as expected :) thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks you're getting everything into one row because you having an extra `for` loop which is not necessary

Try

```
using(SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
     while (dataReader.Read())
     {
          items.Add(dataReader["ColumnName"].ToString());
      }
```

If you need the values for all the columns then better create a class with specific properties and assign each column.

Comment: What is rdr? should it .dataReader["ColumnName"] ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your first problem is that you're using a List of strings to store your data. Lists are inherently one-dimensional. The simplest solution is to use a List of string arrays.

Maybe something like this:

```
SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    string[] row = new string[dataReader.FieldCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        row[i] = dataReader.GetValue(i).ToString();
    }
    items.Add(row);
}
```

Where items is a

```
List<string[]>
```

Comment: I get an error around new string[dataReader.FieldCount]() 'Method name expected'

Comment: Whoops, that's my bad. The line should read:
string[] row = new string[dataReader.FieldCount];
I sometimes confuse when I need the method call (parentheses) when I type "new."

Comment: Another error under items.Add(row); 'The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Add(string)' has some invalid argumenets

Comment: "items" should be a List<string[]>.
The way this would work is that it would gather your data row by row, putting the toString values of your columns into string arrays, with each row having its own array of values. That way, you could iterate through your list of arrays (the rows) and access the columns you want (positions in each array). The first array would hold your column names.

Comment: Be aware that using a collection of arrays like this is a slippery slope.  The code will only get more and more difficult to maintain.  It's a common enough mistake that there are well-established patterns to address it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bekpt1ihrKs

Answer (score 0):

From what you look like you're trying to do, you might be better off using a `SqlDataAdapter` and simply filling a `DataTable`:

```
static DataTable GetDataFromDatabase()
{
  DataTable dt = new DataTable() ;

  using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection( "Server=localhost;Database=sandbox;Trusted_Connection=True;" ) )
  using ( SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand() )
  using ( SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd) )
  {

    cmd.CommandText = "select * from sys.objects" ;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text ;

    conn.Open() ;
    sda.Fill(dt) ;
    conn.Close() ;
  }

  return dt ;
}
```

However, if you're determined to use a data reader, try something along these lines:

```
static List<List<string>> GetDataFromDatabase()
{
  List<List<string>> dataset = new List<List<string>>() ;

  using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection( "Server=localhost;Database=sandbox;Trusted_Connection=True;" ) )
  using ( SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand() )
  {

    cmd.CommandText = "select * from sys.objects" ;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text ;

    conn.Open() ;

    using ( SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
    {

      List<string> columnNames = Enumerable.Range(0,reader.FieldCount).Select( i => reader.GetName(i) ).ToList() ;
      dataset.Add( columnNames ) ;

      dataset.AddRange(
        reader
        .Cast<IDataRecord>()
        .Select(
          record => Enumerable
                    .Range(0,record.FieldCount)
                    .Select( i => record[i].ToString() )
                    .ToList()
        )
        .ToList()
      ) ;
      reader.Close() ;
    }
    conn.Close() ;
  }
  return dataset ;
}
```